# Java access in Google Chrome extension to find timezone offset

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome-extension, timezone-offset

Backstory: I've previously created a Greasemonkey extension for Firefox that converts timestamps to local time by finding the GMT offset of the server location (based on the name of the location it's in) and calling methods from `java.util.TimeZone` in Javascript. Now I want to create an equivalent extension for Chrome.

The problem is that the `java` object that I rely on only seems to be available in Firefox (test it out [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/CWP-Sources/CWP-Examples/Chapter19/CallJava.html)), and as far as I can tell there's still no way to access Java from a Chrome extension (though I may be doing it wrong).

So what I need is either a way to:

1) Access the methods of the `java.util.TimeZone` class (specifically `getTimeZone()`, `getOffset()`, and `getDisplayName()`) from within the extension.

OR

2) Another way of determining the offset of a location based on its name (eg. like those [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)) from within the extension itself, and preferably without any XHR. Proprietary Javascript available in Chrome (if there is any) is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation ?

It seems to have exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Looking at the `setTimezone` method, it seems to take a string like "PST" or "PDT", whereas I need functionality to determine the offset for a timezone given only its name (eg. "America_LosAngeles"), since I don't know whether the timezone is currently in daylight saving or standard time.